# Send more than a 1000 notifications with Admin SDK - Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-fcm

I am trying to implement sending more than a 1000 notifications at a time. My mobile app has to notify workers in a city about new job offerings and I have to notify them.

However, in [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/legacy-fcm) it says that the limit is a 1000 keys in the array so that I can do:

`admin.messaging().sendToDevice(...arrayOfThousandKeys, payload);`

How can I send more than a 1000? Do I split it in 2 or more arrays? Everything is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just call the API as many times as needed to send all the messages.

Comment: I was doing so by calling `sendToDevice` in a for loop, each time with a single but different fcmToken and apparently got rate limited. It has to be an array right?

Comment: I don't know why you wouldn't want to max out the array every call.

Comment: Id have to handle the partition into several arrays etc

Comment: Yes, but each array can be 1000 tokens. So if you're sending to 3000 tokens, that'd be 3 API calls. Btw: even if you'd do 3000 calls, you won't get rate limited.

Comment: I did around 300 `.sendToDevice()` calls. Each call with a single token and after the 100th call or so I got the following message `fcm.googleapis.com network timeout. Please try again.`